# Unable to show markers from database on google maps but can add new markers

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I've 3 forms. I've put google map on 2nd form.I want to provide functionality such that when user proceeds from 1st form to 2nd form he'll be able to add markers on map. In between if he wants to return to previous form those selected markers should be saved. And on proceeding to 2nd form again the markers should be shown on map. Same thing will apply if user returns from 3rd form to 2nd (having map).

I've referred the links: [for details info](http://biostall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Google_Maps_V3_API_Documentation.pdf) & [for examples](http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/multiplemarkers) from Biostall.

Here's my code:

**Model**

```
function get_coordinates($app_id)
 {
     $return = array();
     $this->db->select("latitude,longitude");
     $this->db->from("db_lat_long");
     $this->db->where('application_id',$app_id);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
         foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            array_push($return, $row);
         }
     }
     return $return;
 }
```

**Controller**

```
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        $config['center'] = '23.019698,72.586160';
        $config['zoom'] = '15';
        $config['map_type'] = 'HYBRID';
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        $coords = $this->applicant_model->get_coordinates($app_id);
        //print_r($coords);
        if($coords!==0)
        {
            echo "Coordinates available";
            foreach ($coords as $coordinate) {
                 //$marker = array();
                 //$marker['draggable'] = TRUE;
                 $marker['position'] = $coordinate->latitude.','.$coordinate->longitude;
                 $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
            }
            $data = array();
            $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Coordinates Blank";
            $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
        }
        $app_id=$query;
        $data['app_id']=$app_id;
    // Load our view, passing the map data that has just been created

        $this->load->view('add_application',$data);
```

I'm getting the coordinates in the array for particular user. But unable to show markers.

**View**

```
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(18.520430,73.856744),
      zoom:15,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapProp);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
       placeMarker(event.latLng);
       //alert(event.latLng)
    });

    function placeMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map,
            draggable:true
        });

        var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='textarea' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick='saveData()' /></td></tr>";

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { 
            maxWidth: '50px',
            content: html
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event){
        //alert(event.latLng)
        document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + event.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
    });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(event){
            document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function() {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
    }       
}



function saveData() {

  var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
  var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);

  var latlng = marker.getPosition();

  } 
}
```

Comment: I can save all the data, only thing is that I can't show the markers.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Maybe store a sample data in a hardcoded javascript array/string and show us via JsFiddle?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Okay, I'll try that thing.